# tellg() and seekg() does't work properly

Tags: c++, file, stream

```
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("c:\\1\\a.txt");

    if(fin)
    {
            string readWord1;
            streampos currentPos;
            while(fin >> readWord1)
            {
                    currentPos = fin.tellg();
                    string readWord2;
                    while(fin >> readWord2)
                    {
                            Memo1->Text = Memo1->Text + AnsiString(readWord2.c_str());
                            Memo1->Text = Memo1->Text + "\n";
                    }
                    fin.seekg(currentPos);
                    streampos c = fin.tellg();
            }
    }
```

I want to return file pointer to the currentPos after reading all the words following the readWord1. But in the first step *streampos c* says that pointer is in -1 so *seekg()* doesn't move pointer to *currentPos*

Comment: You need to do `fin.reset()` before calling `seekg`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation (or at least one version of it):

> If the eofbit flag is set before the call, the function fails (sets
>   failbit and returns).

You need to clear the eofbit with `fin.clear()` and then it'll work as expected.